# Как правильно сделать агрегирование?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Имеется queryset следующего вида:

```
<QuerySet [{'applications': 4, 'user': 12192}, {'applications': 63, 'user': 1325}, {'applications': 3, 'user': 12192}]>
```

Как правильно "свернуть" его по юзеру (нужно получить количество `applications` для каждого юзера)? Пробую:

```
queryset.values('user').annotate(Sum(F('applications')))
```

но получаю ошибку `KeyError: 'applications'`.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте:

```
 queryset.values('user').annotate(sum=Sum('applications'))
```

Comment: не помогло, та же ошибка

Comment: applications это название атрибута модели?

Comment: нет, это ранее было получено из Subquery